# Customizing Color with Windows Ribbon Framework

Tags: c++

I am attempting to change the ribbon color of a Windows Ribbon Framework based application. I am not a C++ developer, and I would consider my knowledge of C shaky at best. I do however grasp most of the ribbon XML markup.

Other than custom ribbon xml markup, the application code I have matches what is produced from following the Microsoft development tutorial found here: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?linkid=137046, or here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/windowsribbon/windowsribbon-stepbystep

Most of the developer guide's sample code works with what is produced from the linked tutorial. The code comments on the page on customizing color found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/windowsribbon/ribbon-color mentions the code sample being used during ribbon initialization. I copied the sample code

```
CComPtr<IPropertyStore> spPropertyStore;
if (SUCCEEDED(_spFramework->QueryInterface(&spPropertyStore)))
{
  ...
}
```

into the

```
HRESULT InitRibbon(HWND hWindowFrame)
{
  ...

  ---customize color---

return S_OK;
}
```

function of the Ribbon.cpp file.

This produces a host of errors starting with 
"identifier "_spFramework" is undefined"
As I am not familiar with C++ or WIN32 development, I do not even know where to start to fix this.

edit: added more of the customizing color sample code per Mori's comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to add more of the code within the SUCCEEDED() fiunction, because this is where the problem lies.

Copied from the documentation:

```
// _spFramework is a pointer to the IUIFramework interface that is assigned 
// when the Ribbon is initialized.
if (SUCCEEDED(_spFramework->QueryInterface(&spPropertyStore)))
{ 
    //some code
}
```

_spFramework in this example is a variable (or more specifically a pointer to the IUIFramework interface), and obviously it is named otherwise in your code.

So the problem is: you are trying to use a variable which has never been declared, illegall in C++ (not to mention that you want to access the existing framework and not just any framework).

To fix it, you need to search your code for declaration of the corresponding variable (it will probably look something like IUIFramework *correctname) and use the very same name.

Answer (score 0):

Mori's answer partially fixes the issue, the tutorial declares "IUIFramework* g_pFramework = NULL;" in the ribbon.cpp file.

```
if (SUCCEEDED(_spFramework->QueryInterface(&spPropertyStore)))
{ 
  ...
}
```

should be replaced with

```
if (SUCCEEDED(g_pFramework->QueryInterface(&spPropertyStore)))
{ 
  ...
}
```

Another error is also thrown, propvarutil.h needs to be included before it will compile.

I am aware of the convention of an ampersand to point to a memory location in C, but I have not been exposed to this underscore convention in C++ before. I initially attempted replacing _spFramework with _g_pFramework and it would not compile. Thank you for the help.